# Reactjs rerender input but don't change checked status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i use reactjs to make a quiz app, when I change quiz everything change but the checked status dont change(no props or state here). Change view quiz  by this code:

```
render: function () {
            var content = [];
            var answers = this.props.quiz.answer;
            if (this.props.quiz.type == "single") {
                for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(answers).length; i++) {
                    content.push(<div className="quiz-answer" key={i}>
                        <input type="radio"  value={answers[i]} />
                        {answers[i]}
                    </div>)
                }
                ;
            } else if (this.props.quiz.type == "multi") {
                for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(answers).length; i++) {
                    content.push(<div className="quiz-answer" key={i}>
                        <input type="checkbox"  value={answers[i]} />
                        {answers[i]}
                    </div>)
                }
                ;
            } else if (this.props.quiz.type == "text") {
                content.push(<div className="quiz-answer">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>)
            } else {
                content.push(<div className="quiz-answer"></div>)
            }

            return (
                    <form className="quiz">
                    {content}
                    </form>
            )
```

I make a issue for react too but they said this is only usage question,https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4583

Anyone has this problem like me ?

### Update 1:

https://jsfiddle.net/bsn6ckgv/2/
My flow: when user answered and click next question this will render another question. This is my old version have some bug ,Tomorrow I will update this . But when you check and next , the view change all but checked info didn't remove

### Update 2:

https://jsfiddle.net/bsn6ckgv/29/
I think I need minimize my code as small as it can be instead of update all Logic and many unused component in it. Flow here: You check an answer and click "check Answer" -> You move to a new question . But there no change in checked status :| every thing rerender .... I didn't put any logic check answer here . Seem like need to add state or props for it put to manage the checked info.

### Update 3: fixed

```
            if (this.props.quiz.type == "single") {
                for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(answers).length; i++) {
                    content.push(<div className="quiz-answer" key={questionIndex + "-" + i}>
                        <input type="radio"  value={answers[i]} />
                        {answers[i]}
                    </div>)
                };
            } else if (this.props.quiz.type == "multi") {
                for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(answers).length; i++) {
                    content.push(<div className="quiz-answer" {questionIndex + "-" + i}>
                        <input type="checkbox"  value={answers[i]} />
                        {answers[i]}
                    </div>)
                }
                ;
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle so we can follow along, tell us what actions you are performing on the page to encounter the problem, and the expected vs. actual behavior.

Comment: Hi I update my code to JSFiddle, this is my old code, my new code is better than that but it cant rerender this view. I will update this next day , Thank you

Comment: I downloaded the code to run it local in my environment and in all honesty I don't understand how the app is meant to function. What does "Check Answer" do? Is it taking you to the next question like a multi-step form?

Comment: Hi, I update code in JSFiddle . It is minimized . Check Answer only change to another question in my array

Answer (score 0):

Now I can fix this problem there. Problem here is the keys of component When keys change this checked status reset. SO I set keys with prefix is my Question index and everything now Ok :D